# Intellij Idea's code analysis doesn't make sense

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
public enum FileType {
        json, plainText, csv, XML;
    }
```

In this code, it warns that the semicolon is unnecessary. Is that semicolon optional? It doesn't complain in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon is optional if your enum only lists constants, as in your case.

If, in addition to that, your enum also contains a class body (i.e., it also declares, members, constructors, initializers or methods), the semicolon is required.